# Why are different values being affected in my update sql query?

Tags: sql, select, subquery

A very basic question, I have an update I would like to do when I do the update then it is affecting 2000+ rows but when I just do the select query in the subquery then I get 1726 rows.  I know there is something wrong in my update statement, can  someone please help?

```
update ship_plu 
   set pluc_dt='1-Jan-1999' 
 where pluc_dt in (
                   select sp.pluc_dt 
                     from ship_plu sp,ship s 
                    where sp.pluc_dt between '16-Feb-2014' and '20-Feb-2014'
                          and sp.ship_num=s.ship_num 
                          and s.rcv_dt is null
                   )
```

So above the subquery executed only brings back 1726 rows, but when I execute the entire update query then it effects over 2000 rows, I want to do just 1726?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are updating rows, that shouldn't be updated.

`ship_plu.pluc_dt` might meet the conditions, while `ship_plu.ship_num` is **not**.

This is the wrong way to update.

You should try that:

```
update ship_plu sp 
       JOIN ship s
            ON sp.ship_num=s.ship_num 
   set pluc_dt='1-Jan-1999' 
 where pluc_dt between '16-Feb-2014' and '20-Feb-2014'
       and s.rcv_dt is null;
```

The other choice (assuming `ship_num` is unique and a foreign key somewhere)  is:

```
update ship_plu 
   set pluc_dt='1-Jan-1999' 
 where ship_num in (
                   select sp.ship_num 
                     from ship_plu sp,ship s 
                    where sp.pluc_dt between '16-Feb-2014' and '20-Feb-2014'
                          and sp.ship_num=s.ship_num 
                          and s.rcv_dt is null
                   );
```

I, personally, like first one better.

Comment: Great thanks Alexander, I think the fact that I was putting pluc_dt in was causing the issue, it should be where ship_num in as the ship_num is unique.

Answer (score 2):

You want a correlated subquery.  But you have the inner subquery referring to the outside table.  Try this:

```
update ship_plu sp
   set pluc_dt='1-Jan-1999' 
 where pluc_dt in (
                   select sp.pluc_dt 
                     from ship s 
                    where sp.pluc_dt between '16-Feb-2014' and '20-Feb-2014'
                          and sp.ship_num=s.ship_num 
                          and s.rcv_dt is null
                   );
```

This form of the query will work in any database.  Depending on the actual database you are using, there is other syntax (using `join`) that you could use.

Comment: Thanks Gordon Linoff, this didn't work because I think instead of putting where pluc_dt in I should've put where ship_num in

Answer (score 0):

I checked you query and maybe this can help:

```
    select sp.pluc_dt 
    from ship_plu sp,ship s 
    where sp.pluc_dt between '16-Feb-2014' and '20-Feb-2014'
        and sp.ship_num=s.ship_num 
        and s.rcv_dt is null
```

in this subquery ship_plu table is joining table ship. If there is no relational result in the ship table (condition s.rcv_dt is null has to be satisfied), value from ship_plu table is not returned.

It means update command updates also records, which have same value pluc_dt but its relation in ship table doesn't satisfy condition s.rcv_dt is null.

I would suggest to return record identifier from the query. Change you query this way:

```
    update ship_plu 
    set pluc_dt='1-Jan-1999' 
    where ID in (
        select sp.ID 
        from ship_plu sp,ship s 
        where sp.pluc_dt between '16-Feb-2014' and '20-Feb-2014'
            and sp.ship_num=s.ship_num and s.rcv_dt is null
        )
```

Hope it helps!

Marek